# Link table(s) or redundant columns, SQL optimisation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, optimization

I have two tables, Users and People, both of which share a common attribute, email address, of which they should be allowed to have many email addresses.

I can see three options myself:

1. One link table with redundant columns:

   - Users [id,email_id] and People [id,email_id]
   - EmailAddress [id,user_id,person_id,email_id]
   - Emails [id,address,type]
2. Two link tables without redundancies:

   - Users [id,email_id] and People [id,email_id]
   - PersonEmail [id,person_id,email_id]
   - UserEmail [id,user_id,email_id]
   - Emails [id,address,type]
3. No link tables with redundant columns:

   - Users [id] and People [id]
   - Emails [id,address,type,user_id,person_id]

Does anyone have any idea what would be the best option, or if there is any other ways? Also, if anyone knows how to implement or feel it is better to have link tables without the generated id column please also specify.

Update: a User has many People, a person belongs to a User

Comment: It's not possible to provide an answer to this question without more explanation of what the relationship between Users and People are. Eg: Are 'users' special types of people that can log in? Is there always a User if there is a People entry or vice-versa? Explain a bit more about what you're modelling and you'll be able to get a better answer on how to model it.

Comment: They are conceptually different -- a User has many People, a person belongs to a User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the relationship between user and e-mail is 1:N, not M:N, so in any case you don't need the "link" table `EmailAddress`.

You need to decide which of these possibilities is true for your application:

1. User is always person.
2. Person is always user.
3. There can be a person that is not user **and** there can be a user that is not person.

### Option 1:

Assuming the option (1) is the correct one, the **logical** model should look like this:

[image]

The symbol between Person and User is "category", which at the level of the **physical** database can be implemented either:

- as a "1 to 0 or 1" relationship between separate tables `Person` and `User`,
- or a single table containing both person and user fields, where user fields are NULL for persons that are not also users.

If you have...

- many user-specific fields,
- there are user-specific foreign keys,
- new kinds of persons could be added in the future
- and you don't need to squeeze-out every last drop of performance,

...choose the implementation strategy with two tables.

If there are:

- relatively few user-specific fields,
- there are no user-specific relationships,
- low "evolvability" is acceptable
- and performance is of high importance,

...choose the implementation strategy with the single table.

Similar analysis can be done for each of the remaining possibilities...

### Option 2:

[image]

### Option 3:

[image]

Comment: A user is a person, so it would be option (1) though it conforms to: a user has many user-specific fields, and there are person-specific foreign keys. Could you elaborate a little on what you mean by "choose the implementation strategy with two tables."(?) A lot of thought in this!

Comment: @defaye A category can be implemented as two related tables or as a single table, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Your answer is exceptionally helpful. I've realised that I should perhaps consider having an extra table such that, a User has many Contacts, a Contact belongs to a User, and both User and Contact are specialised types of Person

Comment: I will then be able to have the Person_id as a FK in Email.

Answer (score 1):

If the two entities are conceptually related, then it might make sense to have one table. But if they are two different concepts, then in my experience it is best to have separate tables in order to avoid future confusion. And you're not going to take a big hit anywhere by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the `User` a `Person (People)`?

That would solve the redundant field issue right away.

```
----------
| Person |
----------
    |
 --------
 | User |
 --------
```

The `User` should have the single e-mail field, or mantain the relation with the e-mails table, since `Person` is an abstract concept not related to any application.

I would say start thinking about (re)modeling your schema, so you won't have problems like this.

Read the [Multiple Table Inheritance](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/) in Rails guide, that should get you started.

Comment: The User is allowed to login, the Person is a record of a person belonging to a User.

Comment: You may be onto something here, but I'm not sure how to implement inheritance in rails yet. Looking into it